# How do I get a list of countries in Swift ios?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, nsarray, uipickerview, nslocale

I've already seen two similar questions to mine, but the answers for those questions do not work for me. I have an old project with a list of countries manually typed out inside a set of square brackets.

I can easily use this in my pickerView but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

I will be using the list of countries in a UIPickerView.

Comment: You can use this readymade module. Although it's not free. Take have a look on this tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tovZRZxcTVY&t=23s

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get a list of countries using the NSLocale class's `isoCountryCodes` which returns an array of `[String]`. From there, you get the country name by using `NSLocale`'s `displayName(forKey:)` method. It looks like this:

```
var countries: [String] = []

for code in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes  {
    let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
    let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
    countries.append(name)
}

print(countries)
```

Comment: HIi can i get all states and cities and also filter like particular country all the states and cities . Thanks

Comment: Is localeIdentifier: "en_UK" correct? I thought it should be "en_GB"

Answer (score 16):

**SWIFT 3 and 4**

```
var countries: [String] = []

for code in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes as [String] {
    let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
    let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
    countries.append(name)
}

print(countries)
```

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let languageList = Locale.isoLanguageCodes.compactMap { Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: $0) }
let countryList = Locale.isoRegionCodes.compactMap { Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0) }
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift** You can easily retrieve countries name and their flags emoji.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var countriesData = [(name: String, flag: String)]()

        for code in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes  {

            let flag = String.emojiFlag(for: code)
            let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])

            if let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) {
                countriesData.append((name: name, flag: flag!))
            }else{
                 //"Country not found for code: \(code)"
            }
        }

        print(countriesData)
    }
}


extension String {

    static func emojiFlag(for countryCode: String) -> String! {
        func isLowercaseASCIIScalar(_ scalar: Unicode.Scalar) -> Bool {
            return scalar.value >= 0x61 && scalar.value <= 0x7A
        }

        func regionalIndicatorSymbol(for scalar: Unicode.Scalar) -> Unicode.Scalar {
            precondition(isLowercaseASCIIScalar(scalar))

            // 0x1F1E6 marks the start of the Regional Indicator Symbol range and corresponds to 'A'
            // 0x61 marks the start of the lowercase ASCII alphabet: 'a'
            return Unicode.Scalar(scalar.value + (0x1F1E6 - 0x61))!
        }

        let lowercasedCode = countryCode.lowercased()
        guard lowercasedCode.count == 2 else { return nil }
        guard lowercasedCode.unicodeScalars.reduce(true, { accum, scalar in accum && isLowercaseASCIIScalar(scalar) }) else { return nil }

        let indicatorSymbols = lowercasedCode.unicodeScalars.map({ regionalIndicatorSymbol(for: $0) })
        return String(indicatorSymbols.map({ Character($0) }))
    }
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Same as Ian's but shorter

```
let countries = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes().map { (code:String) -> String in
  let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode: code])
  return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
}

print(countries)
```

Answer (score 7):

also it is a good practise to localize the displayed name of countries. So in addition to vedo27 answer it would be:

```
let countriesArray = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes().map { (code:String) -> String in
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode: code])
        let currentLocaleID = NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier
        return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currentLocaleID).displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
    }
```

Comment: Why do people automatically assume the language that someone wants to see is "en_US" or "en_UK" or whatever? I never understood why more people don't do i the way you suggested. Thanks for adding this!

Answer (score 4):

Here is @vedo27 's answer in Swift 3

```
 let countries = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map { (code:String) -> String in
    let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
    return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update to vedo27's answer but in 
**Swift 5:**

```
let countries : [String] = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map { (code:String) -> String in
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
    }
```

Also for having a sorted array for countries in Alphabetical order add this below in your order after fetching countries list

```
let sortedcountries = countries.sorted { $0 < $1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

Here is an elegant way of doing it in Swift 4

```
var countries: [String] = {

    var arrayOfCountries: [String] = []

    for code in NSLocale.isoCountryCodes as [String] {
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_UK").displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
        arrayOfCountries.append(name)
    }

    return arrayOfCountries
}()
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to improve my answer if you downvote me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 declared as a `var`:

```
var countries: [String] {
    let myLanguageId = "en" // in which language I want to show the list
    return NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map {
        return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: myLanguageId).localizedString(forCountryCode: $0) ?? $0
    }
}
```

Comment: localizedString(forCountryCode: code) is available only from iOS10

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can have it in swift 4 and localized by the system language.

```
import Foundation

struct Country {
  let name: String
  let code: String
}

final class CountryHelper {
  class func allCountries() -> [Country] {
    var countries = [Country]()

    for code in Locale.isoRegionCodes as [String] {
      if let name = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.localizedString(forRegionCode: code) {
        countries.append(Country(name: name, code: code))
      }
    }

    return countries
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for Swift 5.1 (well at least that works for me as a lot of functions has been renamed):

```
let array = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map
{
        (code:String) -> String in
        
        let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        let currentLocaleID = NSLocale.current.identifier
        return NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currentLocaleID).displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: id) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"
}
```

array here is an [String]

Answer (score -1):

For Swift version 5.8.1 and MacOS 13, from iOS 16 Locale.isoRegionCodes is deprecated:

Hence, we can use the following code:

```
import Foundation

class countryDataClass: Codable {
    var isoCode: String
    var name: String
    var countryCallingCode: String
    var currency: String

    init (isoCode: String, name: String, countryCallingCode: String, currency: String) {
        self.isoCode = isoCode
        self.name = name
        self.countryCallingCode = countryCallingCode
        self.currency = currency
    }
    
    var description: String {
            return "{ 'isoCode': \(isoCode),'Name': \(name), 'countryCallingCode': \(countryCallingCode), 'currency': \(currency) }"
        }
}

func getCountryCode(for isoCode: String) -> String {
    let prefixCodes = ["AC": "247", "DG":"246","EH": "212","SS":"211","SX":"721", "AF": "93", "AE": "971", "AL": "355", "AN": "599", "AS":"1", "AD": "376", "AO": "244", "AI": "1", "AG":"1", "AR": "54","AM": "374", "AW": "297", "AU":"61", "AT": "43","AZ": "994", "BS": "1", "BH":"973", "BF": "226","BI": "257", "BD": "880", "BB": "1", "BY": "375", "BE":"32","BZ": "501", "BJ": "229", "BM": "1", "BT":"975", "BA": "387", "BW": "267", "BR": "55", "BG": "359", "BO": "591", "BL": "590", "BN": "673", "CC": "61", "CD":"243","CI": "225", "KH":"855", "CM": "237", "CA": "1", "CV": "238", "KY":"345", "CF":"236", "CH": "41", "CL": "56", "CN":"86","CX": "61", "CO": "57", "KM": "269", "CG":"242", "CK": "682", "CR": "506", "CU":"53", "CY":"537","CZ": "420", "DE": "49", "DK": "45", "DJ":"253", "DM": "1", "DO": "1", "DZ": "213", "EC": "593", "EG":"20", "ER": "291", "EE":"372","ES": "34", "ET": "251", "FM": "691", "FK": "500", "FO": "298", "FJ": "679", "FI":"358", "FR": "33", "GB":"44", "GF": "594", "GA":"241", "GS": "500", "GM":"220", "GE":"995","GH":"233", "GI": "350", "GQ": "240", "GR": "30", "GG": "44", "GL": "299", "GD":"1", "GP": "590", "GU": "1", "GT": "502", "GN":"224","GW": "245", "GY": "595", "HT": "509", "HR": "385", "HN":"504", "HU": "36", "HK": "852", "IR": "98", "IM": "44", "IL": "972", "IO":"246", "IS": "354", "IN": "91", "ID":"62", "IQ":"964", "IE": "353","IT":"39", "JM":"1", "JP": "81", "JO": "962", "JE":"44", "KP": "850", "KR": "82","KZ":"77", "KE": "254", "KI": "686", "KW": "965", "KG":"996","KN":"1", "LC": "1", "LV": "371", "LB": "961", "LK":"94", "LS": "266", "LR":"231", "LI": "423", "LT": "370", "LU": "352", "LA": "856", "LY":"218", "MO": "853", "MK": "389", "MG":"261", "MW": "265", "MY": "60","MV": "960", "ML":"223", "MT": "356", "MH": "692", "MQ": "596", "MR":"222", "MU": "230", "MX": "52","MC": "377", "MN": "976", "ME": "382", "MP": "1", "MS": "1", "MA":"212", "MM": "95", "MF": "590", "MD":"373", "MZ": "258", "NA":"264", "NR":"674", "NP":"977", "NL": "31","NC": "687", "NZ":"64", "NI": "505", "NE": "227", "NG": "234", "NU":"683", "NF": "672", "NO": "47","OM": "968", "PK": "92", "PM": "508", "PW": "680", "PF": "689", "PA": "507", "PG":"675", "PY": "595", "PE": "51", "PH": "63", "PL":"48", "PN": "872","PT": "351", "PR": "1","PS": "970", "QA": "974", "RO":"40", "RE":"262", "RS": "381", "RU": "7", "RW": "250", "SM": "378", "SA":"966", "SN": "221", "SC": "248", "SL":"232","SG": "65", "SK": "421", "SI": "386", "SB":"677", "SH": "290", "SD": "249", "SR": "597","SZ": "268", "SE":"46", "SV": "503", "ST": "239","SO": "252", "SJ": "47", "SY":"963", "TW": "886", "TZ": "255", "TL": "670", "TD": "235", "TJ": "992", "TH": "66", "TG":"228", "TK": "690", "TO": "676", "TT": "1", "TN":"216","TR": "90", "TM": "993", "TC": "1", "TV":"688", "UG": "256", "UA": "380", "US": "1", "UY": "598","UZ": "998", "VA":"379", "VE":"58", "VN": "84", "VG": "1", "VI": "1","VC":"1", "VU":"678", "WS": "685", "WF": "681", "YE": "967", "YT": "262","ZA": "27" , "ZM": "260", "ZW":"263"]
    let countryDialingCode = prefixCodes[isoCode] ?? ""
//    if (countryDialingCode == ""){
//        print(isoCode)
//    }
    return countryDialingCode
}

func getCountriesData() -> [String: (isoCode: String, name: String, countryCallingCode: String, currency: String)] {
    var countriesData: [String: (isoCode: String, name: String, countryCallingCode: String, currency: String)] = [:]
    
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    print("locale:", locale)
    for code in Locale.Region.isoRegions {
//   isoCode ->     print("code", code.identifier)
        if let name = locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: code.identifier) {
            let identifier = NSLocale.localeIdentifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code.identifier])
            let nsLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: identifier)
            let countryCallingCode = getCountryCode(for: code.identifier)
            let currency = nsLocale.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.currencyCode) as? String ?? ""
            countriesData[code.identifier] = (isoCode: code.identifier, name: name, countryCallingCode: countryCallingCode, currency: currency)
        } else {
            countriesData[code.identifier] = (isoCode: code.identifier, name: "Country not found for code: \(code)", countryCallingCode: "", currency: "")
        }
    }

    var countriesDataObj = [countryDataClass]()
    countriesData.forEach { isoCode, data in
        countriesDataObj.append(countryDataClass(isoCode: isoCode, name: data.name, countryCallingCode: data.countryCallingCode, currency: data.currency))
//        print("ISO Code: \(isoCode), Country Name: \(data.name), countryDialingCode: \(data.countryCallingCode), Currency: \(data.currency)")
    }
    
    
    print("len: \(countriesData.count)")
    print("Printing Country Data in JSON Format:")
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(countriesDataObj)
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error encoding to JSON: \(error)")
    }
    return countriesData
}

let countriesData = getCountriesData()
```

I have printed the output in terminal in JSON format.
Output is shown in the image attached.[JSON Country Data Output for IOS 16, MacOS 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1m13.png)

Comment: Please provide text as text , not image or screenshot

Comment: You will get the result when running the code. The screenshot is provided as a reference on how the output looks. The Output may vary according to iOS updates, hence providing a hardcoded output will not be a good solution.